# Python: Replacing strings

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm iterating through pages and I'd like to modify lines containing

```
<span class="font16"></span>
```

How can I correct the code below?

```
text = re.sub(r'<span class="font(.*)"></span><span', r'<span class="font\1">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </span><span', text)
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?

Comment: Right off the bat, I can point out that `(.*)` is greedy and will go as far as it can to the end while leaving `></span><span` afterwards, which will very likely consume more than it should.

Comment: Please see the most voted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Change `.*` to `[^"]*`.

Comment: Instead of a string literal of the kind `"<span class="font\1">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  ..."` you can simply do `r'<span class="font\1">{} </span><span'.format(' '.join(["&nbsp;"] * N))` where `N` is the number of times you want to insert that string.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `.*` will match anything until the end of line, so the match will look like this:

```
16"></span>....
```

which isn't what you want. Use a pattern that stops at the first `"` (since they aren't allowed inside attribute values which are quoted with `"`):

```
r'<span class="font([^"]+)"></span><span'
```

Comment: Ok, now, I've got this: text = re.sub(r'<span class="font([^"]+)"></span><span', r'<span class="font\1">{} </span><span'.format(' '.join(["&nbsp;"] * 8)), text)
But this does not match this: <span class="font16"></span><span style=" letter-spacing:-0.80pt;"> ; where I'd like to insert the signs between font16"> and </span>.

Comment: I'm wondering why the span is empty. You should probably search for `<span class="font([^"]+)">` without the closing `</span>` or the next span..